# Python save module

Tags: python, module, tkinter, save

I got some main program named gui.py and module student.py. In
student.py I got one list conatins (ID, name, surname, ID2, adress) I
imported student.py and it shows normally.

In main program when I click add student, it appends the list but not
save it.

Can you help me please?

```
def odabran () :
    return int(select.curselection()[0]) #odabire metodom curselection-a     (mišem odabrano) i daje pretvara to u int

def dodajRed () :
    lista.append ([ID_v.get(), ime_v.get(), prezime_v.get(),   brojindexa_v.get(), adresa_v.get()])
    setSelect ()

def azurirajRed() :
    lista[odabran()] = [ID_v.get(), ime_v.get(), prezime_v.get(), brojindexa_v.get(), adresa_v.get()]
    setSelect ()

def obrisiRed() :
    del lista[odabran()]
    setSelect ()

def setSelect ():
    lista.sort()
    select.delete(0, END)
    for ID, ime, prezime, brojindexa, adresa in lista :
        select.insert (END, ID)
```

student.py

```
lista = [
  [0, "Damir", "Gugar", "A455KLP", "Sesmislava 2"],
  [1, "Jozo", "Pleh", "585KLPD", "Jozina avenija 44a"],
  [2, "Ana", "Studa", "DD22223", "Ivana Gorice 11"]]
```

The code really works good, but I every time I open the program it's the original list in here, I can't update it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to save student data in this module, it looks like you need to manually input it into the list. Python will not save the contents of anything while running a module, the module has to save the data itself, such as into a text file or some file on a server or database.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your updated list by adding a save function.  I just worked through a similar problem and got it to work.  Here is some sample code:

```
def saveFile () :
    newList = open('student.py', 'w')
    newList.write("lista = " + str(reference to your updated list))
    newList.close()
    print("File Saved")
```

The next time you run your program it will read the same file with the updated info.  Just make sure that list is all that is in the file or it will be deleted each time the save function is ran.